# RGB to YPbPr (YCbCr) conversion and bright picture issues

Tags: operational-amplifier, pcb, components, rgb

I'm working on a specific RGB to YPbPr (component) converter. It is supposed to connect old consoles to a modern flat 240p supportive TV. However I have an issue with luma Y output part. Here is the schematic of the current version I created:[image: schematic]

YPbPr formula is R 0.299 + G 0.587 + B 0.114 and resistors R1-R3 are supposed to do this part

Sometimes the picture is too bright on the top, especially if the picture is black, the picture gets bright on the top and gets even brighter after time. I noticed when I put R6 75ohm resistor as pictured, the brightness decreases a little as it should, however if I lower the resistor value even more, the picture gets screwed up overall.

Right now I'm clueless on how to fix it. Does anyone have any ideas?? I can take a photo of the brightness issue if needed. Many thanks in advance

EDIT: here's the real photo of the effect (some reflection is shown but the main issue is still visible)
[image]

Comment: Do you actually need C1 on the output?

Comment: I would not normally expect to see R6.

Comment: I think C1 is actually required for some TVs and it should be added to the design. So many of them require electrolytic 220uF cap with (-) on the output

Comment: What are you powering the analog mux from? It has significant Ron variation across the power range s. the signal (see figure 1 on page 9 of the datasheet).

Comment: Check if OPAMP is rail to rail one, otherwise it gives you biased output voltage, so luma component is not zero for black RGB.

Comment: The analog mux is powered by 5V and GND from the machine by wires right now. Is 74LVC1G3157 indicative on any issue? Also yes the op-amp is SGM8052 and it states it is rail-to-rail output

Comment: Right now I looked at the op-amp datasheet again and figured out I can use another version of op-amp with /disable output control and perhaps I can remove that insufficient analog mux completely. However what is the best idea to disable the op-amp and make the output go to 0V while the sync is on??

Comment: @user3161354 The most common way of inserting sync is to clamp the PrPb signal during that time. This can be done by shunting the PrPb during sync or opening the PrPb path during sync.

Comment: How do Pb and Pr signals relate to the issue here? Those are actually fine, when I connect only Y to the TV, the issue is still the same. I suspect that analog mux is actually the issue here from my observations. However I cannot come up with any alternative...

Comment: Looking back at the datasheet of the analog mux, I can see this on page 7: ON resistance (peak): Isw = 32 mA; VCC = 4.5 V to 5.5 V Typ: 6.2 Max: 15. This means the switching current is very high for a device like this and it shouldn't exceed around 1mA while LM1881 datasheet page 3 states maximum output sink current is 5mA, meaning analog mux isn't even switched sufficiently. Is this the root cause of this or am I reading it wrong?